# Android Expansion File Downloader under targetSdkVersion 30

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files, targetsdkversion

Because the Expansion.Downloader package supplied by Google is not updated, it can save the downloaded obb files in the correct location, but only if the [PackageName] subdirectory exists in the obb directory. Creating this is also the task of Expansion.Downloader, but this results in an IOException.
What is the reason that the package is allowed to write there but cannot create the required directory?
I would like to create this myself, but under targetSdkVersion 30 I can't do that either.
How can I create the /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/[PackageName] directory if it is not there?

Answer (score 0):

G-o-o-g-l-e, if you yourself can't save the obb files to the obb directory, then I don't need to. I have now found another directory for it that can be written to by my app.